# What causes this equivalent code in Go and C to output differently?

Tags: c, go, programming-languages

I am learning about programming languages and trying to learn about the design principles behind them. Below is code for C and Golang for a simple test of associativity and precedence.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int a(int* n) {
    *n += 1;
    return 2*(*n) - 3;
}

int main() {
    int i = 4, j = 4;
    int sum1 = (i*2) + a(&i);
    int sum2 = a(&j) + (j*2);

    printf("sum1: %d\n", sum1);
    printf("sum2: %d\n", sum2);

    return 0;
}
```

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func a(n *int) int {
    *n += 1
    return 2*(*n) - 3
}

func main() {
    i, j := 4, 4
    sum1, sum2 := (i*2)+a(&i), a(&j)+(j*2)

    fmt.Println("sum1:", sum1)
    fmt.Println("sum2:", sum2)
}
```

C outputs:

sum1: 15

sum2: 17

While Go putouts:

sum1: 17

sum2: 17

I can see in Golang that a() is being evaluated first, but I'm having trouble understanding why Golang does this and the principle behind it. I want to clarify that I don't need both sums to be equal, I'm trying to understand why the expressions are evaluated differently in either language. Essentially, understanding the concept more than the result.

The code is meant to demonstrate that the order they're evaluated in can differ from language to language. For example, in a language without pointers, the reason why the output would be the same is different because using a() would not change the values of i, j in the main method.

Comment: In C, the expressions `(i*2) + a(&i)` and `a(&j) + (j*2)` have undefined behavior, since the operands to `+` may be evaluated in any order.  So this is not valid C.  In both cases, you need to separate the function call from the other operand, e.g. `tmp = i*2; sum1 = tmp + a(&i);`  That way the order is forced.

Comment: Apologies, your reply showed me that my question is still very vague. It's not that I want both outputs to be equal, I'm trying to understand the concept of how each language evaluates expressions. The code is meant to demonstrate that the order they're evaluated in can differ from language to language. For example, in a language without pointers, the reason why the output would be the same is different because using a() would not change the values of i, j in the main method. I've edited the original post to reflect this.

Comment: It seems to be a common misconception about many programming languages that evaluation order is, or ought to be, determined by operator precedence and associativity. This is only true when it affects a mathematical result, e.g.`a + b * c` vs `(a + b) * c` -- but even then, in both cases a, b, and c can be evaluated in any order.

Comment: Order of evaluation is not controlled by associativity and precedence alone.  Since the C code has undefined behaviour, you can't learn anything useful from it except, perhaps, that undefined behaviour should be avoided at all costs (and that may not be obvious to you).  I don't know whether the behaviour of the Go code is fully defined or not.  Nevertheless, the comparison between the two is not useful because the answer produced by at least one of the two code fragments is unreliable — there is no 'gold standard' for what it should produce because its behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @TomKarzes: To be pedantic, in C these expressions have "indeterminate" behavior rather than "undefined" behavior -- per 6.5.2.2.10 in the C11 spec, there are sequence points before and after the call to `a`, so the side effects and accesses are not unsequenced, but rather indeterminately sequenced.  The net effect is that either expression might evaluate as either 15 or 17 in C, but other behaviors are not possible according to the spec.

Comment: @ChrisDodd — I think C11 [§6.5 Expressions ¶2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p2) says that the behaviour is undefined.  [§6.5.2.2 Function calls ¶10](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p10) (to which I think you refer) discusses the situation with respect to a function call in an expression — and the effects may be "indeterminately sequenced".

Comment: In Go the evaluation order for arithmetic expressions and function calls is not specified. [The evaluation order is only defined for function calls, method calls, and communication operations (left-to-right)](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Order_of_evaluation).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: “Indeterminately sequenced” means that, of two things A and B that are indeterminately sequenced, either A is before B or B is before A, but it is unspecified which (C 2018 5.1.2.3 3). 6.5 2 says if a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced with respect to another side effect or a value computation on the same object, the behavior is undefined. Indeterminately sequenced is not unsequenced. “Unsequenced” means A is not sequenced before or after B (5.1.2.3 3 again). This is well established and is necessary as we want `i++` in a function body to be defined…

Comment: … even if the function is called twice within an expression.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: 6.5.2 says that the behavior is undefined if the operations are unsequenced, but my point is the operations are NOT unsequenced, they are indeterminately sequenced due to the function call.

Comment: Thanks all for the responses.
Would it be safe to just say that Go has functions at the top of the order of evaluation then? I am understanding now that C code is not great for learning from, but from what I can gather it is simply that Go evaluates functions first (for a reason I am still searching for in documentation).

Comment: No — it would not be safe to say anything about either the C code or the Go code.  They're exhibiting ill-defined behaviour — any conclusions drawn from observations about either program's behaviour are as likely to be wrong as they are to be right.  "No compiler warnings" does not indicate safety — it just means that any residual bugs are non-trivial for the compiler to detect.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Understood, so it's better to say that, as you said earlier, there's nothing really useful to glean from the comparison of these two code fragments.

Comment: @Peter Do you know why in this case that the function is evaluated first then? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation that provides a rationale behind it, though I could be searching poorly.

Answer (score 0):

In the C example, the order of evaluation is undefined. It seems in this case the following:

```
int sum1 = (i*2) + a(&i);
```

Has been evaluated as:

```
(4*2) + a(&i)  -->  8 + 7
```

In the Go example:

```
(i*2)+a(&i)
```

The `a(&i)` expression is evaluated first, which yields `7`, but leaves `i` as `5`, so `2*5 + 7` is `17`.